# How to solve a *missing ;* in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Good afternoon,
The code below *should* represent the FizzBuzz game.

```
for (var i = 0, i < 100, i++) {
   if(((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) = 0)) {document.write('FizzBuzz')}
else if( ((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) != 0)) {document.write('Fizz')}
else if( (( i % 3 ) != 0) && ((i % 5) == 0) ) {document.write('Buzz')}
else {document.write(i)}
   }
```

This is the error I got in Mozilla Firefox Debugger

```
SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initialize 1.18.
```

I'm stuck.

Comment: Use `;` instead of `,` in your `for (var i = 0, i <100, i++)` - It should be `for (var i = 0; i <100; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible mistakes

1) Inside for loop conditional statement it should be `;` but `,`

2) There is a invalid left side assignment at `((i % 5) = 0)`, it should be `((i % 5) == 0)`

To debug such issue use any linter and properly indent the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
    document.write('FizzBuzz')
  } else if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) != 0)) {
    document.write('Fizz')
  } else if (((i % 3) != 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
    document.write('Buzz')
  } else {
    document.write(i)
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vusougdr/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use semi colons instead of commas in your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
    if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0 ) {document.write('FizzBuzz')}
    else if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0 ) {document.write('Fizz')}
    else if ( i % 3  != 0 && i % 5 == 0 ) {document.write('Buzz')}
    else {document.write(i)}
}
```

You also have a massive parentheses overload! You don't need that many parens, they were also causing you errors.